# Closing form takes time at the time ports are being iterated

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, serial-port

There is the loop to iterate through all ports to connect with specific port.

But at the same time if form is closed it takes time, when I paused and see that when it stuck then the debug point was at the statement of serialport.open().

So when application requests to open the port and at the same time if form is closed, then it hangs for some time and if there are more than 6 or 7 ports it takes more time.

Sample code:

```
string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

int detectPortCount = portNames.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < detectPortCount; i++)
{
    SerialPort discoveryPort = new SerialPort();
    discoveryPort.WriteTimeout = discoveryPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;

        try
        {
            discoveryPort.PortName = portNames[i];
            try
            {
                if (!discoveryPort.IsOpen) discoveryPort.Open();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uex)
            {
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately there is not `Timeout` for the port opening operation. So you cannot influence that. What you can do is to try to open all ports in parallel using `Task`s or `Thread`s. ps the `WriteTimeout` and `ReadTimeout` are only for the reading and writing operation not for the opening part

Comment: @Mong Zhu Actually it is the problem when there is no device connected with PC, it means no connection is established and no writing and reading operation, problem occurs when opening the port only.

Comment: you should be able to open the port irrespective of whether a device is connected or not. Usually the com-ports have a fixed name, that does not change each time you boot the computer. I usually check whether a device is connected when the port is open and I can receive something.

Comment: How long the Open() call takes is entirely dependent on the driver for the serial port.  Normally it takes a fraction of a second for a real serial port, but anything is possible these days since so many device drivers emulate a serial port to make programmatic use of the device easy.   The Timeout property settings have no effect on this.  Nothing you can do about it, other than hoping the port name is stable so you can do this just once and store the discovered name for later use.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually what happens in specific laptop when Bluetooth is on, there are multiple port opens and when application is opened without connecting device and as I close the application, it was iterating through all ports and once it iterates through all ports it accepts request to close then after it closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer:

you can't cancel the `port.Open()` method, but you can make it so that it looks like it closes instantly.

As @MongZhu suggested you can check the ports in parallel:

```
// Not inside the GUI Thread!
ConcurrentDictionary<string, SerialPort> ports = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SerialPort>();

Parallel.ForEach(SerialPort.GetPortNames(), (currentPort) => 
{
    SerialPort discoveryPort = new SerialPort();
    discoveryPort.WriteTimeout = discoveryPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;

    try
    {
        discoveryPort.PortName = currentPort;
        try
        {
            if (!discoveryPort.IsOpen) discoveryPort.Open();
            // do something to check if it's the right port here.
            if(itIsTheRightPort) {
                ports.TryAdd(currentPort, discoveryPort);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uex)
        {
        }
    }
});
```

In addition to that you can always `Hide()` your form before Closing it like:

```
public void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Form.Hide();
    WaitForAllTasksAndThreadsToFinishNiceAndClean();
    Close();
}
```